# strdup pointer version needs a temporary pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings, strdup

I'm implementing a strdup function as an exercise.

```
char* strdupPtr(const char* str) {
    const size_t sz{strlen(str)+1};
    char *save, *temp;
    save = temp = (char*)malloc(sz);
    while((*temp++ = *str++));  // compiler warning with only 1 set of   parenthesis
    return save;
}
```

After a few failures I found out that it works properly when the "save"[(wiki reference)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/string.h/strcpy) pointer is returned but not when "temp" is returned. Why do I need to return save instead of temp directly when dealing with pointers(a subscript array version works without the use of save)?

Comment: Because you change `temp` so that it points to the _end_ of the string.

Comment: the null terminator is added in the line "while"

Comment: when i tried to return &temp[0], which points to the beginning of the array it doesn't work either

Comment: As CO said, because you altered `temp` so it no longer points to the beginning of the array..

Comment: In C++, you should use `static_cast` for the returnvalue of `malloc()`, which needs to be checked against null though. Further, variables should be initialized as close to creation as possible, like you do correctly with `sz`, but which you fail with `save` and `temp`. Lastly, why don't you use `memcpy()` to copy the string?

Comment: memcpy or strcpy would be the best option here, I know that. It's just as an exercise, I'm not allow to use any external function. I do know that I altered temp but, why pointing to the first element doesn't work either? return &temp[0]

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the behavior is the same even using new instead of malloc

Comment: Ok. 1) `temp` points to the beginning of the new string. 2) You modify `temp` in the process of copying the string and it now points to the element right after the null terminator. 3) You take the address of the first element of whatever `temp` now points to. Now refer to #2.

Comment: I never suggested using `new`, and no, the behaviour is not the same, because when they run out of memory, `new` throws `bad_alloc` while `malloc()` returns null. Apart from that, I don't understand what you want to tell me. BTW: Even if you're not allowed to use vendor-supplied `memcpy()`, you can still roll your own, like you do with `strdup()` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the function pointer `temp` is incremented.

```
while((*temp++ = *str++));
```

So if to return `temp` then it will not contain the start address of the allocated memory.

For example these use cases will be invalid.

```
char *p = strdup( "Hello World" );

puts( p );

free( p );
```

Take into account that in C++ it is better to use operator new.
For example

```
char * strdupPtr( const char *s ) 
{
    char *p = new char[std::strlen( s ) + 1];

    std::strcpy( p, s );

    return p;
}
```

Or you could even write

```
char * strdupPtr( const char *s ) 
{
    char *p = new char[std::strlen( s ) + 1];

    return std::strcpy( p, s );
}
```